# Get a copy from queries that returned by mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

lately I faced some problems with mongoose's queries and see very weird results

Hi, I have some problems with queries in mongoose. i use `const user = User.findOne({id})` and it returns query right?
When I use `console.log(user)` everything is fine and get output like this:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("63e76926c4addc1e63c2d20c"),
  first_name: 'Yasin ᅠ',
  id: 5387340288,
  is_bot: false,
}
```

Now when i use object assign on that like `const newUser = {...user}` or `const newUser = Object.assign({} , user)`
then log the user `console.log(user)` get output like this:

```
{
  '$__': InternalCache {
    activePaths: StateMachine { paths: [Object], states: [Object] },
    skipId: true
  },
  '$isNew': false,
  _doc: {
    _id: new ObjectId("63e76926c4addc1e63c2d20c"),
    first_name: 'Yasin ᅠ',
    id: 5387340288,
    is_bot: false,
  }
}
```

and then all my user.update() and ... throw an error or user.first_name will be undefined.
I found the good way to repair my code and that okay, i just wanna know why this is happen, that's very unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Object.assign` or the spread operator to copy the object, the internal properties are also copied along with the document's data, which can cause problems when you try to save the object back to the database or access specific properties.

To avoid this issue, you can use `toObject()` method to convert the Mongoose document to a plain JavaScript object, which will not include any of the internal properties.

For example:

```
const newUser = user.toObject();
```